# Android WebView setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false) only working one time

Tags: android, webview, video-streaming, html5-video, fullscreen

I try to set an video in a Android WebView to fullscreen, to do this i set setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture to false. This is working one time but after ending the fullscreen and trying to set it to fullscreen again it is not working because of this js error:

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.", source:  (1)
```

I initialize the webview like this:

```
webView = root.findViewById(R.id.animeWebView);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

I enter the fullscreen like this:

```
getWebView().evaluateJavascript("(function() { document.querySelector(\"#html5_player\").requestFullscreen(); })();", null);
```

Exit it with:

```
getWebView().evaluateJavascript("(function() { document.exitFullscreen(); })();", null);
```

And than i try to enter the fullscreen again => the failure i wrote above.

I checked the value with getMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture and it is always false.

I use this https://github.com/cprcrack/VideoEnabledWebView to set the video to fullscreen.

Tested on Android 9 - Compile and Target Sdk Version: 30 - Min Sdk Version: 24

Answer (score 0):

This *not clean* workaround is working for me.

```
getWebView().dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, -1, -1, 0));
getWebView().dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, -1, -1, 0));
getWebView().evaluateJavascript("(function() { document.querySelector(\"#html5_player\").requestFullscreen(); })();", null);
```